# How do I derive a regular grammars from this regular expression?

Tags: formal-grammars, regular-expressions

How do I derive a regular grammars from this regular expression?

```
(a or b)*ba(ba)*
```

I'm stuck with the last part
so

```
S -> A | B | C
A -> aA | bA
B -> bC
C -> cD
D->bE ?
E->af | ^ ?
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: May I ask what is the use of this derivation `C -> cD`, when there is no 'c' in the regex? And also is this `(a or b)*ba` not the same as the given regex ?

Comment: There are plenty of references on the web and in textbooks about how to produce a regular grammar from a regular expression. Did you check any of those? Also, I don't see what your grammar has to do with the regexp you're trying to convert. That regexp mentions only characters $a$ and $b$ so I don't understand why there are $c$'s and $f$'s in your grammar.

Comment: Listen to D.W. He is right: Thompson's is the technique that will always work, and will give correct results. In this case one may try one's luck with an ad-hoc approach. Read the expression: do any sequences of $a$'s and $b$'s, then do $b$ followed by an $a$, then repeat any number of $ba$'s. That is not too hard to program as FSA (nondeterministically) is it?

Answer (score 3):

Use Thompson's algorithm to convert the regular expression to a NFA.  Then, you can directly read a regular grammar off, given the NFA: each non-terminal represents one state of the NFA.